# Storing tokens in struct

Tags: c, struct, token

Sorry for the duplicate question, but I'm very new to C programming and can't wrap my head around how to implement previous answers on the same toping into my own code.

I am to read in text from either a file on disk or stdin, sort the words and then present the user with a list of word occurrence (the most occurring word at the top and then in falling order).

I'm currently stuck with storing my tokenised word it a suitable way to later be able to count and sort them. I've decided to go with a struct.

I've written a test-file where I use fgets from stdin to feed it with data.

This is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct words
    {
        char word[500];
        unsigned int count;
    };

    int size = 500;
    char *buffer;
    char token;
    struct words w;

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("--!DEBUG INFO!-- \n Right before the 4-loop now\n--!DEBUG INFO!--\n");
    #endif
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("Please enter word\n");
        fgets(buffer, size, stdin);
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("--!DEBUG INFO!-- \n %c\n--!DEBUG INFO!--\n", buffer);
        #endif
        token = strtok(buffer[i], "\n");
        strcpy(w.word[i], token);
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("--!DEBUG INFO!-- \n %c\n--!DEBUG INFO!--\n", w.word[i]);
        #endif
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c\n", w.word[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling I get a whole bunch of warning messages, most of them stating something similar to this:

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from
      'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
                token = strtok(buffer[i], "\n");
```

The program does however compile, and run until I give it data and hit enter. After that, it crashes with a Segmentation fault: 11 message

```
./tok_struct 
--!DEBUG INFO!-- 
 Right before the 4-loop now
--!DEBUG INFO!--
Please enter word
Test 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I'm very grateful for any help can get!

Comment: Tin all this `#ifdef DEBUG` nonsense, and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but the module is based on learning the very basic of way of doing it, i.e terminal and sublime text in my case.

Comment: Well do it your way for the sake of the course, and my way for the sake of getting a good job. That is, do it both ways.

Comment: @Bathsheba Coming from writing Java in Eclipse last trimester I'm very keen on using a debugger and will do so in the future. But, I do also see a point in not doing it to learn what is actually going on in the background.  :)

Comment: That's odd - I always think a debugger tells you exactly what is going on in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one thing buffer needs to have a size allocated to it, it seems it is just
an uninitialized pointer in your code.

once you do fgets(buffer,...) you enter undefined behavior territory if the 
buffer does not point to a place where the input can be stored.

so first declare buffer as an array

```
char buffer[512]; // or whatever size you deem is appropriate
```

then read the line into the buffer (instead of a for loop use while, you could check line length and quit loop if user didnt enter anything)

```
while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(line),stdin) != NULL)
{
  char* token = strtok(buffer, "\n"); 
  if (token != NULL)
  {
   // in order to get a pointer to the rest of the words you 
   // need to call strtok multiple times and with another 
   // separator since one can assume that there is space between
   // the words e.g.  char* token = strtok(buffer, " \n"); 
   // and to process all words in the line:
   // for (char* token = strtok(buffer, " \n";
   //       token != NULL; 
   //       token = strtok(NULL, " \n"))
   // {
   //  .. here you store your tokens
   // }
  }
}
```

to store the tokens you cannot have the struct as you have it
the char word[500] is just a character array so indexing in that
array and having that as a target for your strcpy makes no sense.

instead you need to have an array of structs.

```
struct words w[200]; // or how many words you are expected to handle
```

now for each word you find you need to look through the array if it
already exists, if yes increment counter else copy in word and set
counter to 1. You should initialize the array to make sure it is set to 0. Keep track of how many words you have in your array e.g. `wordsFound`

```
int wordsFound = 0;
for (char* token = strtok(buffer, " \n"; token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " \n"))
{
  ...
}
```

A final note: strtok modifies the argument that is passed to it, so you cannot store the pointer that is returned. Either you need to copy it as above or you need to allocate space and then copy to it.

Normally one would not have an array of words but instead for instance a linked list of words which grows whenever a new word is found, of course this example can be expanded on to have better lookup etc but I guess that is not your goal for now.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy(w.word[i], token)`; is passing a `char` instead of `char*`. You can have a 2d array in the struct itself and same way you can make `count` contain the frequency of each words.

```
struct words
{
    char word[MAXWORDS][MAXLETTERINWORD];
    unsigned int count[MAXWORDS];
};
```

Then printing each word will be `printf("%s\n", w.word[i]);`. Also here do you need the `strtok`? Because after all you are getting your inputs using `fgets` in every loop iteration. And the `strtok` will run once. You can copy the buffer itself to the `word[index]`.

Buffer doesn't point to any memory. It's UB to use buffer this way. Declare `buffer` to be an `char` array capable of holding a line.`char buffer[MAXLEN];`. Then getting the input would be

```
if(fgets(buffer,MAXLEN,stdin)==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```